# How to get historical content having historical date that happened in current week in Views?

Tags: views, datetime

I have a content type having date field contains historical date like 1897-06-15. Now i need to fetch it by week if historical date's week matches current week in Views? How to do it in views.Any suggestions?

Comment: Just imagine how would you do that in plain SQL, and recreate the same in Views. But I doubt if MySQL supports ISO week numbers :(

Answer (score 0):

I used DAYOFYEAR function.

```
$startDateNumber = date('z', strtotime("-4 days"));
$endDateNumber = date('z', strtotime("+3 days"));

$query = db_select('field_data_field_historical_date', 'fd');
$query->fields('fd');
$query->where('DAYOFYEAR(fd.field_historical_date_value)>=:startDate', array(':startDate' => $startDateNumber));

$or = db_or();
$or->where('DAYOFYEAR(fd.field_historical_date_value)<=:endDate', array(':endDate' => $endDateNumber));

$nid = $query->condition($or)->execute()->fetchField(3);

if (!is_bool($nid)) {
    print_r($nid); exit;
} else {
    print 'no';
}
```